# Electric field due to an uniformly charged ring: problem to plot a specific graphic

Tags: functions, physics, graphing-functions

We know that the intensity of an electric field $E_x$ due to an uniformly charged ring ($R$ is the radius, $r=d(\text{charge $dq$},P)$)

[image]

is
$$E_x=\frac{k_e\ q\ |x|}{(x^2+R^2)^{3/2}}\tag 1$$

where $k_e\approx 9\cdot 10^9$ N$\cdot$ m$^2$/C$^2$, and $q$ is the charge of the ring.

Since $k_e$ is very big, how appropriately should I choose $q$ (the charge) and $R$ (radius of the ring) to obtain the image below?

[image]

**Addendum:**
Here there is an image of the function $(1)$ with $q=R=1$:

[image]

Without $|x|$:

[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Could you be more clear? The curve must always look more or less like that because it's always zero at $x=0$ and has a maximum at $x=R/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @bluestool and Cye Waldman I have forgotten the question of my problem. I have used DESMOS and Geogebra with arbitrary values but the graph are wrongs. Excuse me for my unclear question.

Comment: What are you asking about exactly? As Cye Waldman pointed out, the curve will always look more or less like this, depending on the parameters $q$ and $R$.

Comment: I have programmed this in Matlab and find that $q=1$ and $R=1$ is very much like what you show. However, I don't really know the range of $(x,q,R)$ that you are interested in.

Comment: @bluestool In fact. I have chosen $R=q=1$ and I have not obtain a similar graph.

Comment: Are you sure you plotted $|x|$, because taking $x$ instead yields a different curve

Comment: Can you indicate what you did in particular. Are you sure you represented the equation correctly? In fact, can you show us your result also?

Comment: Well that looks perfectly fine to me. It is certainly odd because the scaling factor is very large, but if you zoom out, you should see the curve you want

Comment: @bluestool I agree with the above.

Comment: I would choose $q=\frac 1{9\cdot 10^9}$. That's the equivalent of plotting $\frac E{kq}$

Comment: @Andrei Excuse me again. Please, can you add an answer or your comment?

Comment: @bluestool Good evening. The same comment of Andrei. Could you add an answer instead of a comment, please?

Comment: Ok, will do that now

Comment: I see that bluestool already added his answer

Comment: @Andrei All users are welcome for my opinion. I'm very happy if you want added another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main factor here is the large factor you are multiplying the function by. When plotting, it can be useful to play with parameters to get a good idea of what the curve looks like. If parameters are too large, the general shape of the curve can be hidden by the sheer size of the values. I believe that is what is happening with your graph here. The graph is odd because the scaling factor is very large, but if you zoom out, you should see the curve you want.

From *Andrei*'s comment,

> I would choose $q=\frac1{9\cdot10^9}$. That's the equivalent of plotting $\frac{E}{kq}$.

Plot for $f(x)=\frac{|x|}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$:
[image: Ordinary function]

Plot for $f(x)=100\frac{|x|}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$:
[image: Scaled up]

Comment: Thank you very very much. But could you add also a graph, please? I hope that not disturb you.

Comment: Sure, I will do that.